# JAVA (Generics, Iterable Interface, Initialize 2-dim Array) Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Matrix

Tags: arrays, generics, matrix, iterable

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Matrix<Integer>[][] m = (Matrix<Integer>[][]) new Matrix[][] {
        {2,34,532,12},
        {923,6,0,67},
        {32,324,3,13}
    };
```

Can someone tell me how to initialize the 3x4 Matrix differently? I keep getting the "Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Matrix" error in all three lines..

Comment: Is this Java? You should specify the language.

Answer (score 1):

It would be good to know what language you are using and what Matrix class you are trying to use, but it looks like you're doing things slightly wrong.

```
# create an int array
int[] i = new int[]{1, 2, 3}

# Create a 2d int array
int[][] i = new int[][]{
  {1, 2},
  {3, 4}
}

# what you have is creating a 2d array, of Matrix<Integer>
Matrix<Integer>[][]

# So either just use a normal int 2d array, or i believe the syntax in C++ is:
Matrix<Integer, 3, 4>
```